# How to search using double select option in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a search using the select option and the logical error here is that I can't make a double select option search. In other words It doesn't work.

here's my code:

```
<form method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="searchtxt" title="Enter name for search" autocomplete="off"/>

                    <select name="searchtxt">
                        <option>
                            Course
                        </option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="searchtxt">
                        <option>
                            1
                        </option>
                    </select>

                    <td style="float:right">
                        <input type="submit" name="btnsearch" value="Search"  title="Search Student" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
    </form>
```

For example "Course 1" then click search.

here's the pic for the search
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xbwrb83yn221ng/search.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Each `select` element should use a different name attribute value.

Comment: I want to combine the both select option so the idea here is I will just throw it to the search bar like this please watch the picture:  [Sample Image](http://dropbox.com/s/fu9mu4y0r2g358q/throw.PNG?dl=0) but I have no idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Each form html element should have unique `name`.

When form is posted, it is posted like this:

```
$_POST['element_one_name'] = $element_one_value;
$_POST['element_two_name'] = $element_two_value;
...
```

So, if you have form elements with duplicate `name`s, the input will be overwritten by next coming duplicate element.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work as you have 2 `<select>` boxes with the same name.
Rename them to be unique:

```
<select name="searchtxt_1">
...
</select>

<select name="searchtxt_2">
...
</select>
```

Comment: I want to combine the both select option so the idea here is I will just throw it to the search bar like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/fu9mu4y0r2g358q/throw.PNG?dl=0 I have no idea on how to do it.